# Why is it showing error Uncaught TypeError: "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"?

Tags: javascript

I have this error, I am trying javascript in HTML document to write "hi".
It is showing error ::
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at 12.html:10

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("mybut").addEventListener("click",dem);
        function dem(){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hi";
        }
    </script>

    <p id="demo">My heritage</p>
    <button id="mybut">
    <p id="demon">Revenge</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your script tag is before the rest of the content within the html and scripts are parsed and executed as they are encountered, the dom element is not available when the script runs

You can move the script execution to the end of body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    

    <p id="demo">My heritage</p>
    <button id="mybut">
    <p id="demon">Revenge</p>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("mybut").addEventListener("click",dem);
        function dem(){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hi";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Another way to handle this is to write your DOM manipulation logic after the DOM has loaded which can be determined by DOMContentLoaded event

```
<body>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
           document.getElementById("mybut").addEventListener("click",dem);
           function dem(){
               document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hi";
            }
        });
    </script>

    <p id="demo">My heritage</p>
    <button id="mybut">
    <p id="demon">Revenge</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Glad to have helped. Consider marking the answer as accepted